# Summing all values of pandas columns in loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, loops

Sample dataframe:

```
       A   B   C
idx    
0      1   2   3
1      2   4   6
2      3   6   9
3      4   8   12
4      5   10  15
5      6   12  18
6      7   14  21
7      8   16  24
8      9   18  27
```

I want to sum each column 3 rows per time, with desired outcome:

```
       A   B   C
   
sum1   6   12  18
sum2   15  30  45
sum3   24  48  72
```

Manually, I would do:

```
sum(df(A[0:2])
sum(df(A[3:5])
sum(df(A[6:8])

# then repeat for B and C
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way, perhaps using a for loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `groupby` like,

```
>>> df
   x   y   z
0  1   2   3
1  2   4   6
2  3   6   9
3  4   8  12
4  5  10  15
5  6  12  18
6  7  14  21
7  8  16  24
8  9  18  27
>>> df.groupby(df.index // 3).sum()
    x   y   z
0   6  12  18
1  15  30  45
2  24  48  72
>>>
```